# how to copy a text area field value to another text area field by clicking on the check box using javascript in rails 4.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using rails 4.0 and I have made a form in which i want to copy a text area to another text area by clicking on the check box, I want to do using rails syntax either through JQuery or javascript.
 This is in my view page:

```
    <tr>
    <td class="feild_name"> Present Address: </td>
      <td class="feild_name"> <%= f.text_area :stud_addr, size: '20x5', placeholder: "Enter the address" %> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="feild_name">Is permanent address same as correspondence address</td>
      <td class="feild_name"> <input type="checkbox" name="copy1" onclick="fcopy(this.form)"> Copy </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="feild_name">Permanent Address:</td>
      <td class="feild_name"> <%= f.text_area(:stud_permaddr, size: '20x5', placeholder: "Enter the permanent address" ) %></td>
    </tr>




    <script>
    function fcopy(f) 
      {
        alert("welcome");
        var x= f.copy;
        if(x.checked == 'true') 
         {
           f.permaddr.value = f.presntaddr.value;
         }
       }
    </script>`
```

When I'm using this it is showing uncaught syntax error at checked inside the function.
How to copy the field into another through check box ?

What will be the rails syntax for copying one field to another ?
Please anybody can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

First, *the Rails syntax* does not exist. The Ruby language has a syntax, JS has a syntax. Rails is *just* a framework written in the Ruby language.

Second, this is not a Rails specific question. You want interactivity on your webpage, so the only solution is to use Javascript (with or without jQuery).

To copy the contents of one field to another with jQuery:

```
$('#destination').val($('#source').val())
```

This assumes there is a textarea with id `source` and one with id `destination`. Use your own selectors to match the elements on your page.

Comment: I have mentioned my rails4.0 codes with my question now can u sort out the problem ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't got your answer.